# card.init(SPI_FULL_SPEED,SD_CS_PIN) returns false for Arduino Mega

Tags: arduino-mega

I am working with a music shield, I have got my code from this site https://www.waveshare.com/Music-Shield.htm it works fine with arduino UNO but when I try to use it on MEGA it give me errors, Well I found that the problem is with this line

```
card.init(SPI_FULL_SPEED,SD_CS_PIN)
```

in uno `SD_CS_PIN=10` I tried to change it to `53` based on this map

```
SPI   Uno   Mega
SS   10   53
MOSI   11   51
MISO   12   50
SCK   13   52
```

which is available on https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=165170.30 but still it returns false. What other options do I have to make it work on `MEGA`?

Thing that I am trying

```
#define SD_CS_PIN=10
#define VS_XRESET A0
#define VS_DREQ   A1
#define VS_XDCS   A2
#define VS_XCS    A3
void VS10XX::init(void)
{
  SPI.begin();
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV2);
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(VS_XRESET, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(VS_DREQ, INPUT);
  pinMode(VS_XDCS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(VS_XCS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(VS_XDCS, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(VS_XCS, HIGH);

  reset();
}
```

In setup I added used this code but still does not work

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);//setting pin 53 to input
  player.begin();
}
```

the error code when I attempt to `init` sd card is `0` which says

```
/** timeout error for command CMD0 */
```

Comment: did you try the examples of the shields library? 'your' code is from insides of the library

Comment: @Juraj yes it is exactly that code, I am just changing parametrs to find out where is the problem

Comment: I think nothing needs to be changed for Mega. only set the pin 53 mode to output in .ino

Comment: @Juraj I removed all modifications from library and added` pinMode(53, OUTPUT);//setting pin 53 to input` to `setup()` but still does not work

Comment: from SD library comment of card.init: "The value one, true, is returned for success and the value zero, false, is returned for failure.  The reason for failure can be determined by calling errorCode() and errorData()."

Comment: @Juraj The error code is 1 and error data is 0 I tried to look it up in this source https://github.com/arduino-libraries/SD/blob/master/src/utility/Sd2Card.h but could not find it yet

Answer (score 1):

53 is a SS pin if the Mega is SPI slave. Pin 10 is connected to shield to select it as a listening slave. So let the parameter set to pin 10. Additionally on Mega set pin 53 to output, otherwise the Mega can 'fall' into SPI slave mode.

SPI pins 50, 51 and 52 are connected to the ICSP header too. The 6 pin ICSP header is on the same place relative to Uno an Mega common pin headers.

[image]

Comment: thanks very much, Sorry for my noob question, I am new to arduino, So you mean I must set `SD_CS_PIN` to `10` and only add `pinMode(53, OUTPUT);` after `SPI.begin();` ?  I updated the question

Comment: if it worked with 10 on Uno, then let it 10. for the shield the pin 10 is on the same place on Mega and Uno. 10 is a logical choice for SS on Uno. it must be an output (for the same reason 53 must be output on Mega) if SPI library is used

Comment: I tried based on what you said but it still returns false. I showed my code in question